# Maintaining the dimension in a 3D list after for loop

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm working with lists and I came up with a question. So basically, I have a 3D list in which I'm trying that after a for loop I maintain the second and penultimate element of the inner list, my code does the work, but it changes from a 3D list to a 2D list and I don't want that (this is just an example, mylist can have more elements) here is my code

```
mylist = [[[0, 4, 3, 5, 1], [0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 3, 1], [0, 3, 5, 1], [0, 2, 5, 3, 1]], 
          [[0, 4, 1], [0, 2, 1], [0, 4, 3, 1], [0, 4, 5, 1], [0, 4, 3, 1]]]

aux = []
for i in mylist:
    for j in i :
        if len(j) >= 4: 
            aux.append(j[1:-1])

print(aux)

# aux= [[4, 3, 5], [2, 3], [3, 5], [2, 5, 3], [4, 3], [4, 5], [4, 3]]
```

I got almost what I need, but I was expecting this output

```
aux = [[[4, 3, 5], [2, 3], [3, 5], [2, 5, 3]], [[4, 3], [4, 5], [4, 3]]] #Mantains the 3D dimension
```

I'm working on my list comprehension, but I'm not quite sure how to do this, this is what I try

```
aux = [[j[1:-1] if len(j) >= 4 for j in i] for i in mylist] 
#But I get a syntax error
```

I don't know if there is a easier way to do this (must be, but I'm the guy who complicate things) maybe a a much easier list comprehension that I'm not seeing, so any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it right, only you have to move the if statement to after for in list comprehension:

```
aux = [[j[1:-1] for j in i if len(j)>=4] for i in mylist]
```

output:

```
[[[4, 3, 5], [2, 3], [3, 5], [2, 5, 3]], [[4, 3], [4, 5], [4, 3]]]
```

Comment: Oh I see now!, I wasn't completely lost, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You were really close!

This should work. Look it over and see the logic involved

```
aux = [[j[1:-1] for j in i if len(j) >= 4] for i in mylist]
```